# React Native KeyboardAvoidingView on iOS does not update its position when the view behind gets updated

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm using the `KeyboardAvoidingView` in a dynamic form where errors are being displayed or disappear while typing.

On Android, everything works fine and the KeyboardAvoidingView "moves" when an error appears, to always show the keyboard right below the input field.

However on iOS, whenever an error appears at the top of the input, the input gets pushed down, and the keyboard doesn't move. Because of that, the input gets behind the keyboard and can't be seen while the user is typing.

Is there a simple fix for that, or do you necessarily need to play with a useEffect to update the position of the keyboard manually?
I'm also open to any other alternative, if there is!

Comment: Hey, did you get the answer for this problem? I'm having the same in my project :(

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't :/